# Intellij custom VM options

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a custom vm option in most of my run configurations: "${eclipselink-javaagent}", I need to edit that, but I'm not able to find any way to do that. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out IntelliJ does not have a custom macro option (as Eclipse does, which was what put me on the wrong leg), the value was defined as an environment variable.